# Find or create s3 bucket in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I'm finding that cdk tries to recreate S3 buckets every time I deploy. If I don't specify a bucket name, it generates a new junk bucket name every time. If I do specify a name, it refuses to deploy because the bucket already exists. How can I make it "upsert" a bucket?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const dataIngestBucket = new Bucket(this, 'data-lake', {
  bucketName: `${this.props.environmentName}-my-company-data-lake`
});
```

Comment: this is not the expected behavior, if this bucket is in the root of your stack. I suggest you to check with `cdk diff` right before and after a deployment, to check what is changing when deploying the same code. It seems there's a circular dependency in the code.

Comment: This is happening to me, too. My S3 stack is getting deployed although the `cdk diff` states no changes on my S3 stack.

Answer (score 4):

Let me provide an answer using python. It can be easily traced and converted to any other languages.

Please refer to [aws_cdk.aws_s3.Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/Bucket.html) class.

There you will find parameters to specify during class creating which allow you reach your goal, namely `auto_delete_objects=True` and `removal_policy=cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY`.

Comment: Very helpful. I think @TechFree's response regarding best practices is likely to be the correct approach in most cases, but this does the job.

Comment: This looks like an awful solution! I'd never ever ever like to have the policy set to destroy in production - you'd lose your customers' data, wouldn't you? But you still need to maintain your app and update the stack from time to time.

Comment: @AndrejMohar , you are giving more context to the question that there was originally along with your rude personal opinion - what is your reasoning? Security? Data retention? What if there are no such requirements, hence, this solution is appropriate.

Also, your motivation of "maintaining app and  update stack from time to time" has nothing to do with stack deletion. Once stack is deployed, it should be updated, not re-created for applying consequent changes.

Comment: @KyryloKravets, that was my point actually, the OP is trying to _update_ a stack containing an S3 bucket and the S3 bucket update is either failing if the bucket name was set (this can happen even if you _don't change anything_ on the S3 bucket), or a new one is created with a totally new name. From my understanding, the mentioned solution automatically deletes all the bucket contents, then the bucket, and then recreates it from scratch - all of this on stack update and not on stack delete. You can't convince me this is a good solution in prod, except maybe for buckets with disposable data.

Comment: Having said that last part, even for the buckets containing disposable or junk files, I'd still rather keep them _without any auto-removal options enabled_ and keep the cleanup under my control (e.g., clean them up manually using scheduled tasks). Having anything with auto-delete capabilities is in my opinion a terrible idea that will get you in a world of trouble sooner or later.

Answer (score 3):

CDK would do an update on your stack resources automatically if CDK code is updated.
For example, when you execute a CDK stack that creates a bucket for the first time, bucket would be created  with provided configuration.
When you update your CDK code to say update lifecycle policy of the bucket or add a CORS, as part of the same stack, the update of the stack would automatically update the bucket - it would not recreate the bucket as Cloud Formation knows that there is an update on an existing stack.

In your case, it seems the stack is being re-created after a removal when the stack resources still exists. This causes Cloud Formation to create a new stack and its resources which were not removed when stack was destroyed.

Generally, issues occur when stack update fails and it is in rollback state, for example. In that case, redeploy would try to create the bucket again and fail.
In that case, possible option could be:

1. Delete the buckets
2. Delete the stack
3. Redeploy to re-create

Many times, we do not want to delete the resources, as they contain data; in that case, you can use another library such as boto3 for python in the CDK code, to check if the resource exists - if not create via CDK. This would cause CDK code to be not attempt creating the bucket if it exists ( CDK itself cannot be used to see if say S3 resource exists already - at least have not seen how to achieve this)

Another important point is the removal policy associated with the resource

[troubleshooting_resource_not_deleted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting_resource_not_deleted)

> My S3 bucket, DynamoDB table, or other resource is not deleted when I
> issue cdk destroy
>
> By default, resources that can contain user data have a removalPolicy
> (Python: removal_policy) property of RETAIN, and the resource is not
> deleted when the stack is destroyed. Instead, the resource is orphaned
> from the stack. You must then delete the resource manually after the
> stack is destroyed. Until you do, redeploying the stack fails, because
> the name of the new resource being created during deployment conflicts
> with the name of the orphaned resource.
>
> If you set a resource's removal policy to DESTROY, that resource will
> be deleted when the stack is destroyed.

However, even with the removal policy as DESTROY, Cloud formation **cannot delete** a non-empty bucket. Extract from the same link below -

> AWS CloudFormation cannot delete a non-empty Amazon S3 bucket. If you
> set an Amazon S3 bucket's removal policy to DESTROY, and it contains
> data, attempting to destroy the stack will fail because the bucket
> cannot be deleted. You can have the AWS CDK delete the objects in the
> bucket before attempting to destroy it by setting the bucket's
> autoDeleteObjects prop to true.

Best Practice is to

1. Design stack resources in such a manner that they have minimal updates being applied which can cause failure. So a stack can be created with say mostly static resources such as ECR, S3 which do not change much and is independent generally of the main application deployment stack which is more likely to fail.
2. Avoid manually deleting the stack resources which breaks a stack's inconsistency
3. If a stack is deleted, ensure stack's owned resources are also deleted.

Answer (score -2):

Get rid of having fix names!

With

```
 final IBucket myBucket = Bucket.Builder.create(this, "mybucket")
            .bucketName(PhysicalName.GENERATE_IF_NEEDED).build();
```

(Java, but doesn´t matter)

Do you get a "random-Named" Bucket.
Described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/resources.html

Use it like this in your template (here nested stack)

```
@Nullable NestedStackProps templateProps = NestedStackProps.builder()
            .parameters(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                put("S3Bucket", myBucket.getBucketName());

            }})
            .build();
```

Or you still have a fix name (get rid of!!) then get them with:

```
final IBucket myBucket = Bucket.fromBucketName(this, "mybucket", "my-hold-bucket-name");
```

But you can not doing things like:

```
if (!myBucket) then create
```

(pseudo code)

No ressource-check at compile/runtime!